# android + parse : join two tables and query it

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is regarding Parse backend.

I have two tables:

**Event:** objectId, contact, heading, latlng, noi, ACL, parent, user(pointer to User), data_to, featured, weblink, updatedAt, organization(pointer to Organization), address, emailid, tags, major, rsvp(boolean), createdAt, image, date_from, description, is_major_event, group(pointer to Group)

**Event_stat:** objectId, ACL, createdAt, event(pointer to Event), rsvp(join/maybe/seen), updatedAt, user(pointer to User)

I want to join these tables and resultant table will be used to query like:

> Select * from [join result] where event_stat_user="asdcvb" AND
>   organization="abc" AND (event_stat_rsvp="join" OR rsvp="maybe") sortby
>   event_stat_updatedAt

Can anyone help me how can i achieve this in Android ?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-join-several-tables-with-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: FYI only http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/ :(

Comment: @milapTank Still its client requirement to me.. Ofcourse, I am aware of it, but still..

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I need solution for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to create a sub query:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery("event_stats");
query.setLimit(1000);
query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseInnerQuery = new ParseQuery<>("event");
parseInnerQuery.whereEqualTo("organization", ParseObject.createWithoutData("organization", Data.getValue(OrganizeActivity.CURRENT_ORGANIZATION)));
query.whereMatchesQuery("event", parseInnerQuery);
query.include("event");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null && list != null && list.size() != 0) {
            List<Event> listEvent = new ArrayList<Event>();
            for (ParseObject parseObject : list) {
                listEvent.add(Event.getEventById(getValue(parseObject, "event")));
            }
            masterEventAdapter.setEvents(listEvent);
            } else {
        }
    }
});
```